# Angular: bind two form controls to the same model

Tags: angular, algorithm, typescript

I have two controls created using the `ControlValueAccessor` interface - a date picker and an age selector - and would like to bind them together using the same value. These represent retirment date and age and the user should be able to modify one and see the other input update.

I have done this by subscribing to the `form.valueChanges` observable, like this:

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
  if (val.retirementDate !== this.currentDatePickerValue) {
    // retirement date changed
    this.currentDatePickerValue = val.retirementDate;
    setTimeout(() => this.retirementAgeCtrl.setValue(this.currentDatePickerValue));
  } else if (val.retirementAge !== this.currentAgePickerValue) {
    // retirement age changed
    this.currentAgePickerValue = val.retirementAge;
    setTimeout(() => this.retirementDateCtrl.setValue(this.currentAgePickerValue));
  }
});
```

Without the `setTimeout()`s, this gives rise to a stack exception, but with them it works. Unfortunately it's not as efficient as it could be, since this code runs a dozen times or more when either of the inputs changes.

How can I accomplish this so that the code only executes as many times as necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass [emitEvent](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue) option as false

> emitEvent: When true or not supplied (the default), both the statusChanges and valueChanges observables emit events with the latest status and value when the control value is updated. When false, no events are emitted.

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
  if (val.retirementDate !== this.currentDatePickerValue) {
    // retirement date changed
    this.currentDatePickerValue = val.retirementDate;
    this.retirementAgeCtrl.setValue(this.currentDatePickerValue, {emitEvent: false})
  } else if (val.retirementAge !== this.currentAgePickerValue) {
    // retirement age changed
    this.currentAgePickerValue = val.retirementAge;
    this.retirementDateCtrl.setValue(this.currentAgePickerValue, {emitEvent: false})
  }
});
```

Comment: Hmm. That subscription block still executes six times with the code modified as per your answer, but I no longer need the timeouts so that's an improvement. Any idea why valueChanges would be emitting further events with that { emitEvent: false }? It only executes once if I remove the two setValue statements.

Comment: @serlingpa: Ideally it should not, can only tell after seeing the full application. See this example, check the console after entering values in the first input box. https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-emit-false?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts. Posible to replicate your case here?

Comment: I realised I was calling `setValue()` within the date picker and age picker themselves in response to `writeValue()` so I modified that code and now the subscription block is being executed once as expected. Thanks!